# HttpContext.Current is null in Response.Redirect Extension method

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net project on framework 4.6.1. HttpContext.Current is fine in normal flow. But if I use Response.Redirect "Extension" method HttpContext.Current is null there.

For normal Response.Redirect it's working fine. I have applied different solutions like checked it without async/await method etc but behaviour is same.

any idea?

```
  public static void Redirect(this HttpResponse response, string url, string target, string windowFeatures)
{

    if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(target) || target.Equals("_self", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures))
    {
        response.Redirect(url);
    }
    else
    {

        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

        if (page == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot redirect to new window outside Page context.");
        }
        url = page.ResolveClientUrl(url);

        string script;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures))
        {
            script = @"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}"");";
        }
        else
        {
            script = @"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"");";
        }
        script = String.Format(script, url, target, windowFeatures);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), "Redirect", script, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use: `this HttpContext context` instead of `this HttpResponse response` with the antipattern: `HttpContext.Current`?

Comment: did you inherited the `Page` class in your extension class?

Comment: @JoelHarkes this fixed my issue. If you could create the answer I will mark that as Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Joel Harkes** comment fixed my issue

> why not use: this HttpContext context instead of this HttpResponse
>   response with the antipattern: HttpContext.Current?

Creating extension method of HttpContext resolved the issue.

```
public static void Redirect(this HttpContext context, string url, string target, string windowFeatures)
{

    if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(target) || target.Equals("_self", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures))
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
    else
    {

        Page page = (Page)context.CurrentHandler;//HttpContext.Current.Handler;

        if (page == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot redirect to new window outside Page context.");
        }
        url = page.ResolveClientUrl(url);

        string script;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures))
        {
            script = @"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}"");";
        }
        else
        {
            script = @"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"");";
        }
        script = String.Format(script, url, target, windowFeatures);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), "Redirect", script, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very important to understand where you call it. If there is no page that calling this, then yes is null, and its null because there is no page to write the redirect commands (and the other commands there).

For example if you call it from a new thread (not the page), then is null.

Also you can get this error if you call it from `global.asax` in some section of it.